# HEY... what are you doing?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> With **H** I taste good.
> With **E** I smell good.
> With **Y** I snoop in the hood.

What am I... with **HI**?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are:

> the letters **NOS**.

*With H I taste good.*

> Adding an 'H' to the end gives us **NOSH**, another word for food (which *tastes good*).

*With E I smell good.*

> Adding 'E' gives **NOSE**, something which *smells well*.

*With Y I snoop in the hood.*

> Adding 'Y' makes you **NOSY**, *prying* into what others are up to in the *neighbourhood*...

So, with HI you are:

> **[NOSHI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noshi)** - a ceremonial origami fold, given as a gift to express 'good wishes'. (So thank you!)

Comment: Very cute little puzzle and a nice answer to go along with it :)